# Unable to display Morris.JS Chart on Codeigniter page using JSON Data as input for Charts

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter, morris.js

I am using the latest Codeigniter and MorrisJS.
I have created a View for the Charts and passing dynamic data through JSON, but that does not seem to work.
I have made sure that all the dependent JS and CSS for MorrisJS is mapped on the View.
When I give dummy data statically into the Chart options, it generates the chart perfectly.
Only does not work when the JSON data is passed.
Please could you guide me on this, I am sure I have made a silly mistake, but am not able to figure it out.

My View:

```
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
    <script>
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            data: <?php echo $graphData; ?>,
            xkey: 'MonthName',
            ykeys: ['totalTicket'],
            labels: ['Value']
        });
    </script>
```

My Controller:

```
    public function index(){
        $x['graphData']=json_encode($result);
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('common/main_top_navbar');
        $this->load->view('reports/trends');
        $this->load->view('common/footer',$x);
    }
```

My Model:

```
class Reports_model extends CI_Model{
    function display_monthOnMonth_records(){
        $this->db->select('MONTHNAME(CreatedOn) as MonthName, count(TicketID) as totalTicket');
        $this->db->from('TBL_tickets');
        $this->db->group_by('MonthName');
        $this->db->order_by('
            FIELD(
                MonthName,
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            )
            ');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I see on the Chrome Browser/page Inspect(F12), that data is showing for the data input, but it is not creating the Chart on Page.

From the Browser Inspect Result:

```
<script>

        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            data: {"data":[{"MonthName":"January","totalTicket":"2500"},{"MonthName":"February","totalTicket":"2200"},{"MonthName":"March","totalTicket":"2350"}]},
            xkey: 'MonthName',
            ykeys: ['totalTicket'],
            labels: ['Value']
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `index()` method, change :

```
    $x['graphData']=json_encode($result);
```

into :

```
    $x['graphData']=json_encode($result->data);
```

From what I see from the output, you have extra `data` parent.

Comment: I tried to make the change as you had mentioned, but still it is failing.
`$x['graphData']=json_encode($result->data);`

I getting the below error:
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object.

On the Browser Inspect I see this:
`Morris.Bar({
   element: 'myfirstchart',
   data: null,
   xkey: 'MonthName',
   ykeys: ['totalTicket'],
   labels: ['Value']
  });
`

Comment: How about change it to : `$x['graphData']=json_encode($result['data']);` ?

Comment: Great! This works fine...
`$x['graphData']=json_encode($result['data']);` Did the trick.